# Upgrade kubernetes from v1.11 to v1.15

Tags: excel, kubernetes, upgrade

My source k8s cluster version is v1.11.5 and the dest k8s cluster version is v1.15.2 with in-place upgrade.

K8S Cluster Status.Three master nodes with k8s controll plane:

```
NAME   STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
a1     Ready    master   23h   v1.11.5
a2     Ready    master   23h   v1.11.5
a3     Ready    master   22h   v1.11.5
```

I didn't use kubeadm upgrade because the enforced k8s skew policies.I followed the steps below:

[step 0] kubectl drain node a3 and remove all k8s components on a3.

[step 1] use kubeadm init to install v1.15.2 k8s on node a3 and undrain node a3.

[step 2] redo the steps above on node a2 and a1.

After installed v1.15.2 k8s on each node,K8S Cluster Status becomes:

```
NAME   STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
a1     Ready    master   23h   v1.15.2
a2     Ready    master   23h   v1.15.2
a3     Ready    master   22h   v1.15.2
```

**So my question is is there any problem on this upgrade solution?**

Because the k8s version skew policy says k8s does not support upgrading on cross y version.For example,I have to upgrade k8s from v1.11 to v1.12 and then from v1.12 to v1.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should generally do each version upgrade. Not only can there be intermediary upgrades that need to happen for things like CNI plugins, running Kubelet with more than one version of skew is not supported. So if you were going to do this, you would instead have to drain and stop every node, then do the upgrade, then start them again :) That would obviously mean a complete downtime, as opposed to doing each hop which allows rolling upgrades, which are usually preferred.

Comment: Doing each version upgrade means 1.11 to 1.12 to 1.13 to 1.14 to 1.15,that's a little bit panic:)
And some details about **"running Kubelet with more than one version of skew is not supported"** please:)
**"you would instead have to drain and stop every node"**:yes,i have to stop each node,install new version k8s and start them,but at the same time,the other two nodes provider services.

Comment: No, to jump the whole upgrade chain you would have to stop all nodes at the same time. Fully shut down your cluster.

Comment: Does **stop all nodes** means drain all k8s masters and workers at the same time during the whole upgrade chain?Why?Please give me some detail informations about this action.And in my case,there is a vip on these k8s master nodes.k8s components use vip to connect with kube-apiserver.

Comment: You have to do that because you are insisting on not following standard procedures. If you run each minor upgrade in order, then you don’t have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it is not an upgrade. You have run 'kubeadm init to install v1.15.2'  which means it is a fresh install of v1.15.2

Comment: Yes,it's a fresh install not an upgrade.So is there any risk point on this solution,like the kube-apiserver mix versions running on v1.11.5 and v1.15.2

Comment: check kubectl get cs and kubectl get po -n kube-system.

Comment: if the output shows all the pod core pods are running then you are good to go. deploy a sample web application and verify you can access it.

Comment: Yes,i have done what you said and it seems good.But i just worry about this solution is agaist the k8s skew policy.